# set-car!, set-cdr! unbound in racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

I am just trying to do very simple code with `set-car!` and `set-cdr!` in `racket`, but I got the error: `expand: unbound identifier in module in: set-car!` and `expand: unbound identifier in module in: set-cdr!`

Aren't they defined in `racket`? Could anyone help?

Comment: Which language do you choose? Set the language to R5RS.

Comment: I have `#lang racket` in the beginning, when I set `#lang R5RS`, it gives me an error: `Module Language: invalid module text standard-module-name-resolver: collection not found: #<path:R5RS/lang> in any of: (#<path:/home/chengtie/.racket/5.1.1/collects> #<path:/usr/share/racket/collects>)`

Comment: Use `#lang r5rs` -- lower case.  (But using the r5rs language is not going to make for a pleasant experience.)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to import `mutable-pairs-6`, like this:

```
(require rnrs/mutable-pairs-6)
```

Those procedures were moved to a different module and renamed to `mcons`, `mcar`, `mcdr`, `set-mcar!`, `set-mcdr!`, `mlist` to emphasize that they operate on mutable data, unlike their immutable counterparts.

Comment: Thanks for your comment... what about `cadr`? it seems that `mcadr` does not exist...

Comment: Sadly those procedures (`mcadr`, `mcdar`, etc.) don't exist, you'll have to implement their functionality by hand

Comment: Define it yourself! `(define mcadr (compose mcar mcdr))`

Comment: Somehow although I `require` that module, it still tells me `set-cdr!: unbound identifier in module`. Could it be that they are not there anymore?

Comment: There is no `mlist` in this package. So to use it we also need to add `(require compatibility/mlist)`

Answer (score 13):

Óscar López's answer is correct, but doesn't explain why normal pairs are immutable.

In Racket (and its predecessor, PLT Scheme, since version 4), cons cells are immutable by default. Most Scheme programs never need to modify cons cells, and having them be immutable allows many optimisations. (For example, `list?` and `length` can both be constant-time.)

For cases where mutability is needed, there's mpair (as mentioned), and more usefully, there's boxes.

Comment: [Obligatory reference here.](http://blog.racket-lang.org/2007/11/getting-rid-of-set-car-and-set-cdr.html)

Comment: SICP Chapters 4 and 5 use mutable cons cells for the metacircular evaluator and for register machines, so the code from the book (https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/code/index.html) doesn't quite run 'out-of-the-box' on Racket v7.2.

Comment: You can use the package neil/sicp with racket to get set-car! and set-cdr! for the SICP. I'm doing it right now, and it looks like it works.

Something like that in the command line works: ` racket -i -p dyoo/simply-scheme -p neil/sicp -l xrepl ` - see https://planet.racket-lang.org/package-source/neil/sicp.plt/1/18/planet-docs/sicp/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the issue is about section 3.4 (Concurrency) in SICP, here's the code to implement `parallel-execute` and `make-serializer`:

```lisp
(require rnrs/mutable-pairs-6)
(require compatibility/mlist)

(define (parallel-execute . procs)
  (map thread-wait
       (map (lambda (p) (thread p))
            procs)))

(define (make-serializer)
  (let ((mutex (make-mutex)))
    (lambda (p)
      (define (serialized-p . args)
        (mutex 'acquire)
        (let ((val (apply p args)))
          (mutex 'release)
          val))
      serialized-p)))

(define (make-mutex)
  (let ((cell (mlist false)))
    (define (the-mutex m)
      (cond ((eq? m' acquire)
             (if (test-and-set! cell)
                 (the-mutex 'acquire)
                 (void)))
            ((eq? m 'release)
             (clear! cell))))
    the-mutex))

(define (clear! cell)
  (set-mcar! cell false))

(define (test-and-set! cell)
  (if (mcar cell)
      true
      (begin (set-mcar! cell true)
             false)))
```