# why set-car! implement like this does not work

Tags: scheme, racket

In Racket, there is not a `set-car!` function, and I want to implement it like this:

```
(define myset-car!
  (lambda (list value)
    (if (not (list? list))
        #f
        (set! list (cons value (cdr list))))))
```

But it does not work, it can't change the value of a list if I use it like this:

```
 (define p (list 2 3 4))
 (myset-car! p 'a)
 p  ; p still is (2 3 4)
```

Can anyone tell me why? what's wrong with what I do?

Comment: It's a bad idea to call a parameter `list`, it'll clash with the built-in `list` procedure

Comment: Also, see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475366/set-car-set-cdr-unbound-in-racket) for future reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody suggested macros yet, so here's a solution that would work for your case:

```
(define-syntax-rule (myset-car! lst val)
  (if (not (list? lst))
      lst
      (set! lst (cons val (cdr lst)))))

(define p (list 2 3 4))
(myset-car! p 'a)
p
```

yields

```
'(a 3 4)
```

since macros a.k.a. syntactic forms transform your source code directly without invoking procedures.

Macro expansion in Dr Racket yields (i.e. your source code gets transformed to)

```
(define-syntax-rule (myset-car! lst val)
  (if (not (list? lst)) lst (set! lst (cons val (cdr lst)))))

(define p (list 2 3 4))
(if (not (list? p)) p (set! p (cons 'a (cdr p))))
p
```

Answer (score 4):

The code in the question doesn't work because in this line:

```
(set! list (cons value (cdr list)))
```

... you're assigning a new value to the `list` *parameter*, but that's a change local to the procedure, it won't be reflected "outside" the procedure in the `p` variable. You're simply pointing the `list` parameter to a different list, but `p` is still pointing to the original list once the procedure returns.

In fact, `set-car!` has to be a primitive operation. But fear not, in Racket there *is* a `set-mcar!` and a bunch of other operations for mutable pairs, if unbound you just have to import [`mpair`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/mpairs.html):

```
(require scheme/mpair)
```

And consistently use all of the mutable pair operations. For instance, here's how to build a mutable list:

```
(define mlst (mcons 1 (mcons 2 (mcons 3 '()))))
```

Or alternatively:

```
(define mlst (mlist 1 2 3))
```

To access elements:

```
(mcar mlst)
=> 1

(mcdr mlst)
=> (mcons 2 (mcons 3 '()))
```

And of course, to mutate elements:

```
(set-mcar! mlst 0)
mlst
=> (mcons 0 (mcons 2 (mcons 3 '())))

(set-mcdr! mlst '())
mlst
=> (mcons 0 '())
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to accomplish your need.  One way is to avoid mutable operations all together.  For example:

```
;; If 'list' is a list? then change it's first value to 'value'
;; otherwise return the list.
(define my-fancy-cons
  (lambda (list value)
    (if (not (list? list))
        list
        (cons value (cdr list)))))

(define p '(2 3 4))
(set! p (my-fancy-cons p 'a))
```

The function `my-fancy-cons` does not destructively modify its `list` argument. You then get to do things like:

```
(define p '(2 3 4))
(define px (my-fancy-cons p 'a))
```

and still have `p` unchanged.  If you need to change it, do as I did in the first snippet, use `set! p ...`

As to you original question, within your `lambda`, the parameter `list` is local and `set!` only changes what `list` 'points' to.