# Metacircular evaluator of Scheme in Dr. Racket

Tags: scheme, racket, evaluator, metacircular

When I am trying to run an evaluator in Dr. Racket, it shows the error: 
'Module Language: there can only be one expression in the definitions window'.

Obviously there are multiple definitions in this window, an evaluator has multiple definitions, so how can I run these multiple definitions ? or is there any other method to run the evaluators.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to add `#lang racket` as the first line in the definitions window.

Comment: @uselpa even that is not working, set-car! is unknown to #lang racket. set-car!: unbound identifier in module in: set-car!

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @Sylwester i am using Scheme

Comment: For set-car! see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475366/set-car-set-cdr-unbound-in-racket. You could also try `#!r6rs` instead of `#lang racket`.

Comment: So you have "#lang scheme "on the first line? Try "#lang planet neil/sicp" if your code has to do with SICP. Otherwise you might need #!r5rs or #!r6rs as first line. You can also choose a language in the menu. I

Comment: @uselpa ,  #lang r5rs works, but again I got stuck in 'error'. But resolved this by: '#lang r5rs
(#%require (only scheme/base error))'. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#lang r5rs
```

resolve set-car! problem, but error was unknown this time. I resolved this by (#%require (only scheme/base error)).

So I add these two lines to make my evaluator run:

```
#lang r5rs
(#%require (only scheme/base error))
```

Answer (score 6):

I am new to Racket, and when I was trying to run my very first program I too encountered this error.

I added `#lang racket/base` at the beginning of the source code and it solved this problem.