# unbound identifier in module - DrRacket

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I am learning scheme and working with the metacircular interpreter for examples and practice, and I am getting the following error:

```
 set-car!: unbound identifier in module in: set-car!
```

And the error is being caused by the following code:

```
(define (add-binding-to-frame! var val frame)
  (set-car! frame (cons var (car frame)))
  (set-cdr! frame (cons val (cdr frame))))
```

I have two questions... First, what does the error mean? And secondly, am I missing a let function?

Comment: Check this question, it might help http://stackoverflow.com/q/9475366/1197333

Comment: #!racket (a completely different language than Scheme) does not have `set-car!` and `set-cdr!`. Use #!r6rs instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Racket a pair allocated by `cons` is immutable by design - therefore there are no `set-car!`. To allocated a mutable pair, use `mcons`. To mutate a mutable pair, use `set-mcar!` and `set-mcdr!`.

Here is a complete program:

```
#lang racket
(define p (mcons 1 2))
(set-mcar! p 3)
p
```

Comment: Made the appropriate changes, and I still get the same error. Thank you for the answer though.

Comment: I have added a complete program. Note that mcons, mcar, mcdr, set-mcar! and set-mcdr are exported by racket/base. Use (require (only-in racket/base mcons mcar mcdr set-mcar! set-mcdr!)) if you are using a language, where the mutable versions aren't included from the start.