# scheme which support set-car! and set-cdr! in sicp

Tags: scheme, racket, org-mode, sicp, mit-scheme

I am reading [SICP 4.1.3 Evaluator Data Structures](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html#%_sec_4.1.3)

```
(define (make-frame variables values)
  (cons variables values))
(define (frame-variables frame) (car frame))
(define (frame-values frame) (cdr frame))
(define (add-binding-to-frame! var val frame)
  (set-car! frame (cons var (car frame)))
  (set-cdr! frame (cons val (cdr frame))))
```

However, the `set-car!` is reported as unbounded in racket.

Then tried implements of 'GNU Guile 2.2.6', "GNU mit-scheme 10.1.10", unfortunately, `set-car!` are all not bound.

Search through the whole book of original version:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.org"  -exec grep --color -nH --null -e "set-car!" \{\} + |wc -l
27
```

There are 27 occurrences through chapter 3 4 and 5,
and within chapter 3 I change setcar! to setcar of elisp. but elisp is not a good option for chapter 4 of metalinguistic abstraction.

The chapter 4 is bits of difficult thus now risk of adventure.

I find the good solution [set-car!, set-cdr! unbound in racket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475366/set-car-set-cdr-unbound-in-racket)

```
(require rnrs/mutable-pairs-6)
```

As a solution, If replace `set-car!` `set-cdr!` with `set-mcar!` `set-mcdr`, the codes of chapter 4 and 5 will run smoothly by racket implementation?

Comment: It seems that `set-car!` and `set-cdr!` are both supported in [Chez Scheme](https://github.com/cisco/ChezScheme)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bear in mind that Racket supports several languages. In `#lang racket` pairs are immutable, which means that the mutators `set-car!` and `set-cdr!` aren't present.
If you want to use `#lang racket` you can work with list of boxes. A box can hold one value and you can use `set-box!` to change the value held by the box. Alternatively you use mutable pairs (and mutable lists) built with `mcons` and `mlist`, but it can turn out a bit cumbersome.

The pairs in `#lang r5rs` or `#lang sicp` are mutable which means, you can use the SICP code as is.

https://docs.racket-lang.org/sicp-manual/SICP_Language.html?q=sicp

In case you wonder why pairs are immutable in `#lang racket`, see:
https://blog.racket-lang.org/2007/11/getting-rid-of-set-car-and-set-cdr.html

Comment: is it possible to set `#lang r5rs `from command line? I use it in the emacs' org babel.

Comment: You can use the executable `plt-r5rs`. Or use `racket -I r5rs`